# Are there conditions in Spring data queries?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Repository Interface and the following method to find persons by their `organizationalUnit` and `type`.

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Person p "
        + "JOIN p.organizationalUnit ou "
        + "JOIN p.type type "
        + "WHERE p.name = ?1 "
        + "AND ou = ?2 "
        + "AND type = ?3")
    List<Person> filterPerson(String name, OrganizationalUnit u, Type t);
}
```

The above code works fine, but if the given values of `u` or `t` are `null` I need to find all persons in spite of their type or unit.

Is there a way to declare a statement in dependence of a condition?

Something like:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Person p "
        + "JOIN p.organizationalUnit ou "
        + "JOIN p.type type "
        + "WHERE p.name = ?1 "
        + {?2 != null ? "AND ou = ?2 " : ""}
        + {?3 != null ? "AND type = ?3 " : ""}
        )
```

Comment: You are already using spring repository...so what if  you add a custom implementation of some method and build the query inside that method? [here](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-eight-adding-functionality-to-a-repository/) you can find a good example

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's what I'll do if the query becomes more complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do it this way:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Person p "
        + "JOIN p.organizationalUnit ou "
        + "JOIN p.type type "
        + "WHERE p.name = ?1 "
        + "AND (?2 is null OR ou = ?2)"
        + "AND (?3 is null OR type = ?3)"
        )
```